# getting count on same column using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table like this, in which I need to set the male and female counts for the primary key id:
**summaryTable:**

```
    id   femaleCount   maleCount
    -----------------------------
    s1      ?            ?
    s2      ?            ?

... and so on
```

There is a **detail** table as below, that has the users corresponding to each id of *summaryTable*:

```
    id    parentId   userId
    --------------------------
    1     s1         u1
    2     s1         u2
    3     s2         u2
    4     s2         u2

...and so on
```

The third is the user table like this:
**userTable**:

```
userId   gender
-------------
u1       M
u2       F
u3       F
..and so on
```

I have to update the summary table with the counts of male and female. So as per the above, for id=s1, femaleCount should be set to 1 , maleCOunt=1
For id=s2, femaleCOunt should get set to 2 and maleCount=0

Is this possible to do using an UPDATE query in MySQL?

I tried the following, but this returns the sum of occurences of a user i.e. if u1 occurs 2 times for p1(say), then it will return count as 2 and not 1:

```
SELECT 
  d.parentId,
  SUM(gender = 'F') AS 'F#', 
  sum(gender = 'M') as 'M#'
FROM detailsTable as d 
JOIN userTable as c on c.userId = d.userId
GROUP BY d.parentId;
```

Also tried as below, but it gave an error:

```
select d.parentId, 
    count(case when c.gender='M' then 1 end) as male_cnt,
    count(case when c.gender='F' then 1 end) as female_cnt,
 from detailsTable d, userTable c where d.userId=c.userId group by d.parentId, d.userId ;
```

Further, my problem doesnt just end at the select, I need to get the values and then update these in the summary table too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be rusty on the syntax for MySql but I believe this does what you need. The CASE/SUM is effectively a pivot to get the counts, then you can update the table as normal.

```
UPDATE  summaryTable AS st
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT parentId
                           ,SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END) femaleCount
                           ,SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END) maleCount
                     FROM   userTable d
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT parentId, userId FROM detail) ut ON d.userId = ut.userId
                     GROUP BY parentId
                   ) AS c ON c.parentId = st.parentId
SET     femaleCount = c.femaleCount
       ,maleCount = c.maleCount
```

Comment: Like I said, a user's gender should not be counted twice, if the user is repeated. The above solution is updating it like that. If the same user is occuring more than once in details table for a given parentId, then the above query counts it as many times

Comment: Sorry I missed that - added a distinct subquery on the detail table. Does that solve it?